# Check emails are genuine

Tags: email, phishing

unitedstatescustoms66@gmail.com tescoextrashippingcompany147@gmail.com

I have received messages from the email letting me know about luggages and parcel being sent a soldier whom I have been talking to online. Don't know of he is real. Don't know if the email addresses are genuine. The emails requesting to pay freight fees for safekeeping of those baggages until the soldier gets to me roughly around the 4th or 5th Dec. He doesn't know that I am doing this background checks before for the freight. So please can someone find out about the email addresses.

Comment: Those are obviously fake email addresses. No major customs organization or large shipping company will use a gmail address as their primary point of contact. These are as fake as can be.

Comment: This is obvious "fake claim" email that intended to defraud any gullible person response to the email.  This is a bad question because it doesn't give sufficient information or sample email like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lltgbhhnxtwo9l7/BACorrespondance.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 3):

They're fake/phishing. Here's why:

1. Why would the US Customs and Border Protection agency use gmail.com for their email domain, instead of a .gov domain?
2. You don't know if the person you were chatting with is real.
3. They're asking for a fee. That's not neccessarily a red flag by itself, but in combination with the above, it definitely is.